# Rainbow Kit. React app failures jest test with rainbow-kit component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

A react app (built with create-react-app ts) fails jest test after a rainbow kit component was added.

```
 ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import {
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import { useState } from 'react';
      2 | import cn from 'classnames';
    > 3 | import { ConnectButton } from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit';
        | ^
      4 |
      5 | import { UrlForm } from 'components';
      6 | import classes from 'App.module.scss';
```

What could be going wrong with it?
Tests run and pass successfully after ConnectButton removed.

Comment: https://github.com/rainbow-me/rainbowkit/issues/461